# Jquery Find Using Wildcard

Tags: jquery

I need to find the id of a div that starts with chart using wildcard:

So, given the following DOM

```
<div id="box5" class="box-container">
    <div class="inner-box wide">
        <div class="top-box handle">Some content</div>
        <div class="chart"><div id="chart1_div">A chart</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My guess was.

```
 var $elementToFind = $("[id^=chart]");
 var found = $('div#box5').find($elementToFind).attr('id');
 alert(found);
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: I think you should reconsider your approach. Having a need to use wildcards despite the power of jQuery selectors seems a bit backwards to me. I would use a class and a data- attribute instead: `<div class="chart-div" data-id="1">`.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? I got the correct alert when i ran it on jsfiddle, see: http://jsfiddle.net/GordnFreeman/9NpwN/

Comment: This seems to work for me. Is this the markup you're actually dealing with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var found = $('div#box5').find("[id^=chart]").attr('id');
alert(found);
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$("#box5").find("[id^='chart']").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var found = $('div#box5').find('div[id^=chart]');
alert(found);
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/KQ9fR/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector;

```
$('#box5 div[id^="chart"]')
```

Reference; http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be working fine for me in jQuery 1.7.1:

Please take a look at this jsFiddle.  Is your code in the document ready?

http://jsfiddle.net/HYr2V/